# Spark 3 with Pandas Vectorised UDF's

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking at using Pandas UDF's in PySpark (v3). For a number of reasons, I understand iterating and UDF's in general are bad and I understand that the simple examples I show here can be done PySpark using SQL functions - all of that is besides the point!

I've been following this guide: https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/20/new-pandas-udfs-and-python-type-hints-in-the-upcoming-release-of-apache-spark-3-0.html

I have a simple example working from the docs:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Iterator, Tuple
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

pdf = pd.DataFrame(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [8, 9, 0]), columns=["x", "y", "z"])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

@pandas_udf('long')
def test1(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return x + y

df.select(test1(col("x"), col("y"))).show()
```

And this works well for performing basic arithmetic - if I want to add, multiply etc this is straight forward (but it is also straightforward in PySpark without functions).

I want to do a comparison between the values for example:

```
@pandas_udf('long')
def test2(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return x if x > y else y

df.select(test2(col("x"), col("y"))).show()
```

This will error with `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`. I understand that it is evaluating the series rather than the row value.

So there is an iterator example. Again this works fine for the basic arithmetic example they provide. But if I try to apply logic:

```
@pandas_udf("long")
def test3(batch_iter: Iterator[Tuple[pd.Series, pd.Series]]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    for x, y in batch_iter:
        yield x if x > y else y

df.select(test3(col("x"), col("y"))).show()
```

I get the same ValueError as before.

So my question is how should I perform row by row comparisons like this? Is it possible in a vectorised function? And if not then what are the use cases for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out. So simple after you write it down and publish the problem to the world.

All that needs to happen is to return an array and then convert to a Pandas Series:

```
@pandas_udf('long')
def test4(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series([a if a > b else b for a, b in zip(x, y)])

df.select(test4(col("x"),col("y"))).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent the last two days looking for this answer, thank you simon_dmorias!

I needed a slightly modified example here. I'm breaking out the single pandas_udf into multiple components for easier management. Here is an example of what I'm using for others to reference:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame(([1, 2, 3,'Fixed'], [4, 5, 6,'Variable'], [8, 9, 0,'Adjustable']), columns=["x", "y", "z", "Description"])
df = spark.createDataFrame(xdf)

def fnRate(x):
    return pd.Series(['Fixed' if 'Fixed' in str(v) else 'Variable' if 'Variable' in str(v) else 'Other' for v in zip(x)])


@pandas_udf('string')
def fnRateRecommended(Description: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    varProduct = fnRate(Description)

    return varProduct

# call function
df.withColumn("Recommendation", fnRateRecommended(sf.col("Description"))).show()
```